# Can't access phpmyadmin after restarting computer

Tags: phpmyadmin, xampp, restart

My xampp has been installed correctly, I've created databases in my phymyadmin already. But after shutting down my computer and opening it again, I can't access it anymore. It says [This webpage is not available](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tgP1F.png) my control panel is up and running so I don't see any reason why it doesn't work. Please help!!!

Comment: Try to start all services from system tray

Comment: Are your apache server and mysql running ?